# Parsing CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I parse a large csv file in the following format:

`A,1,X:1,X:1,X:1,X:1...`

I need to save `A`and all the `1`'s. I want to save the `1`'s as comma separated:

`A` `1,1,1,1,1,1...`

Example of data:

```
4217,23,4217:0.1304,11045842:0.0870,11027563:0.0435,15055960:0.0435,12556773:0.0435,10317812:0.0435,21268053:0.0435,14982717:0.0435,12560416:0.0435,21684075:0.0435,12177392:0.0435,878710:0.0435,21777845:0.0435,11045966:0.0435,17109375:0.0435,15701596:0.0435,10312162:0.0435,11045878:0.0435
```

What I expect:

`4217` `4217,11045842,11027563,15055960,12556773,10317812,21268053,14982717,12560416,21684075,12177392,878710,21777845,11045966,17109375,15701596,10312162,11045878`

Comment: What have you tried? What does the example data supposed to look like after your filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have your input as a string in a variable, say `row`,

```
#Filename: test.rb

row = "4217,23,4217:0.1304,11045842:0.0870,11027563:0.0435,15055960:0.0435,12556773:0.0435,10317812:0.0435,21268053:0.0435,14982717:0.0435,12560416:0.0435,21684075:0.0435,12177392:0.0435,878710:0.0435,21777845:0.0435,11045966:0.0435,17109375:0.0435,15701596:0.0435,10312162:0.0435,11045878:0.0435";

row=row.split(',').map do |x|
        if(x.index(':')!=nil)
            x[0..(x.index(':')-1)]
        else
            x
        end
    end

keyElement = row[0];
arrayElement = row[2..-1];

puts keyElement;
for i in 0..arrayElement.length-1
    print(arrayElement[i] + ", ");
end
puts arrayElement[-1];
```

Here `keyElement` would contain 'A' and `arrayElement` would contain the comma seperated values as an array.

For your sample data, it gives:

```
>>ruby test.rb
4217
4217, 11045842, 11027563, 15055960, 12556773, 10317812, 21268053, 14982717, 12560416, 21684075, 12177392, 878710, 21777845, 11045966, 17109375, 15701596, 10312162, 11045878, 11045878
```

I would however recommend a hash, assuming you need to associate the array with the value 'A':

```
#row is mapped as before

hashElement = Hash.new();
hashElement[row[0]] = row[2..-1];
```

Comment: @Yogzzz: Answer edited as well. It works perfectly for your sample data. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Yogzzz: I've added the values of `keyElement` and `arrayElement` I obtained for the sample data as well.

Comment: Please see my updated question with what I hope to return back. Thank you.

Comment: @Yogzzz: You need the array of X's, not the array of 1's eh? Answer changed.